# Find min value in 2d array with MPI

Tags: c, mpi

Recently began to study MPI technology
The task is to find the minimum value in the matrix.
Search itself parallelize for faster work.
But I can’t put my mind to how to make a parallel version from the sequential version of the program
I ask for help

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "mpi.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
int rows, cols, min, value, n;
int done = 0, numprocs, rank, i, j;
srand(time(NULL));
double startwtime = 0.0, endwtime; 
int namelen; 
char processor_name[MPI_MAX_PROCESSOR_NAME]; 
MPI_Init(&argc,&argv); 
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&numprocs); 
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&rank); 
MPI_Get_processor_name(processor_name,&namelen); 
    while (!done) { 
    if (rank == 0) { 
        printf("Enter the height/width of the matrix\n");
        scanf("%d",&rows);
        scanf("%d",&cols);
        startwtime = MPI_Wtime(); 
    }
    if (rows == 0 || cols == 0) {
        done = 1; 
    } else { 
        int **arr = (int **) malloc(rows * sizeof(int*));    //creating 2d array
            for (i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
                arr[i] = (int *) malloc(cols * sizeof(int));
        }
        for (i = 0; i < rows; i++) {         //Array filling
            for (j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
                arr[i][j] = rand();
            }
        }
        for (i = 0; i < rows; i++) {      // output of the array to the screen for clarity
            for (j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
                printf("%d\n",arr[i][j]);
            }
        }
        min = arr[0][0];                                      
        for (i = 0; i < rows; i++) {                              //find min value
            for (j = 0; j < cols; j++) {                          //
                if(min > arr[i][j]){min = arr[i][j];}         //need to parallize
            }
        }    
        if (rank == 0) { 
            endwtime = MPI_Wtime();
            printf("min = %d\n", min); 
            printf("wall clock time = %f\n", endwtime-startwtime); 
            fflush( stdout ); 
            for(i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
                    free(arr[i]);
            }
            free(arr);
        }
    }
}
MPI_Finalize();
return 0;
}
```

Sorry for my bad English
I am hope for your help

UPD: Added a similar function, but the program gives out garbage. It seems to me that this is due to the creation of an array based on pointers. And most likely I misused the functions

```
        MPI_Scatter (&arr[0][0], rows*cols/numprocs, MPI_INT, &arr[rows][cols], rows*cols/numprocs, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);    
        min = arr[0][0];
        for (i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
                min = arr[i][j];
            }
        }   
        MPI_Reduce(&min, &value, rows*cols/numprocs, MPI_INT, MPI_MIN, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

Comment: allocate in contiguous memory, scatter(v), find the minimum of the sub matrix and reduce.

Comment: Could you tell me how to do it right? How to correctly render and whether the request will change after that

Comment: I guess I could, but what would you learn? Do your homework, and if you are stuck, then update your question with your code and describe where you are stuck at, then you will be more likely to receive some help.

Comment: I suspect that these functions should be used. And that the task is solved in a few changes. But I can’t understand how to use these functions correctly and how the search condition can change

Comment: Can you help me?

Comment: start writing code that works with a 1D array, and then move to a 2D array.

Comment: and start by assuming `rows % numprocs == 0`, and initializing `rows=cols=-1`